# When should I use Docker's container name?

Tags: docker

When I ran `docker ps -a`, I got

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
e3be2faeb751        centos:latest   touch /var/log/test   2 minutes ago       Exited (1) 2 minutes ago                        insane_kirch6
```

What is the name, *insane_kirch6*, for?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can name your own containers with `--name` when you use `docker run`. If you do not provide a name, Docker will generate a random one like the one you have.

Check their documentation for naming at *[Legacy container links, The importance of naming](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#the-importance-of-naming)*

Comment: Thanks. That document answers my question. So the name will be use when
linking container.

Comment: Yes that along with just general usability :)

Comment: can you provide a small example of the `--name`?

Comment: docker run -d --name "container-name" "image-id"

Comment: The reference says *"Warning: The --link flag is a legacy feature of Docker. "*

Answer (score 61):

And even more importantly, you can run named containers again later with `start`:

```
docker start named-container
```

Or:

```
docker start --interactive named-container
```

Answer (score 39):

Not only for visibility, but it also can be used as `container_id`,
in docker commands like `start`, `stop`, `exec`, `rm`, ...

When you want to run a command in an existing container (running or exited), you will identify the container either by **name** or **container_id**.

Examples:

Create a container named ***qqqq*** and start a process "sleep" 1 minute, and then exit.

```
$ docker run --name qqqq ubuntu sleep 60
```

Run another command in the container ***qqqq***:

```
$ docker exec qqqq ps -aef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 04:21 ?        00:00:00 sleep 60
root        11     0  3 04:21 ?        00:00:00 ps -aef
```

Delete the container ***qqqq***:

```
$ docker rm qqqq
qqqq
```

Comment: I am sure this will help people

Comment: Note: The --name should be followed by the 'run' . Else it fails