# How to name a container with docker run

Tags: docker, containers

How is possible to assign a name to a container while using docker run with interactive mode?

For example, running this command

```
docker run -d -it docker_image_already_created sh
```

when checking with `docker ps` the name is autogenerated. How can the container name be passed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to Use Docker's Container Name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230812/when-to-use-dockers-container-name)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Provide the [`--name` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#name---name):

```
docker run -d --name your_name -it docker_image_already_created sh
```

Comment: out of curiousity, why name tag has two dashes and it has only one? new to docker.

Comment: Because `--name` doesn't have a shorthand version. It's a common concept in tools to offer a short and a long version of providing command line arguments (e.g. `-d` could also be written as `--detach`). Usually shorthand versions save you from typing multiple characters, but since you only have a limited set of characters available, this option is usually reserved for commonly used ones.

Comment: `-it` is actually two parameters, `-i` (interactive) and `-t` (tty), just being combined. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground.